# get scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

everybody. I am new to AngularJS and find it very interesting, but I am a bit unclear about the following situation.

```
 app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function ($scope, http, filter)
    {
        $http({
            method: CTHocUri,
            url: 'get',
            async: true,
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.CTH = response.data; //response.data=two Object  
        })
    }])

app.directive("myCustom1",['$http', function ($compile,$http) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
       console.log(scope.CTH); // I can't get... scope.CTH=undefined
 }
}])
```

I can't get value scope.CTH. ??

Comment: give scope.CTH an initial value in the controller, and then you'll see it in the directive's console.log. the reason you dont see it now is that it's being initialized inside the $http success function, which is async

Comment: @NitsanBaleli I wouldn't expect the scope to be shared between a directive and a controller.

Comment: you maybe right, but still the main issue here is the async nature of $http. the scope variable will be set in a later point in time

Comment: what exactly is directive needing to do with `CTH`? May need a `$watch` if you need to process it before passing to view

Comment: i want to get CTH.length to custom pagination my list

Comment: Can't you do that in the view? Still not enough detail on what directive is doing exactly. Using the `$broadcast` idea below is one certain way to make sure it is defined though. Another is using `$watch`

Answer (score 1):

There is a VERY simple way to SEE what the issue is:

In your html, merely surround your directive with an ng-if conditional based on CTH:

```
<span ng-if="CTH">
   <my-custom-1></my-custom-1>
</span>
```

That's it.

What this does is that your directive will only be born/instantiated when CTH is set to non-null/non-undefined, i.e. when $http returns asynchronously.  With this, your code will work. As such, there is no need for watching or broadcasting for this type of simple serialization of asynchronous events when you can simply leverage Angular's built-in '$watch's.

**NOTE 1:** I do not know what your architecture is and am not suggesting what you need to do.  I am merely showing you why your code won't work and how you have been caught in a simple asynchronicity trap.

**NOTE 2:** I assume your directive is 'as -is'.  In other words you have access to the parent's scope (i.e. the controller's scope). If your directive's scope were isolated (i.e. you had a scope:{..(attrs)..} defined in the directive) you will not have 'simple' access to the parent scope. Your code will be different--eg you can pass bits and pieces of your scope to the directive attrs. However, the ng-if will still work since it is on the controller's scope.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Creative solution; I tested it and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The directive and the controller are two completely different entities.  If it helps you can think of them as different classes.  They will not share the same scope.

You could create an isolated scope on the directive and pass the CTH variable into it.  Conceptually something like this:

```
app.directive("myCustom1",['$http', function ($compile,$http) {
    return {
       scope { cth : "=" },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
       console.log(scope.cth); 
 }
```

Then in your HTML, do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<my-Custom1 cth="CTH">
</div>
```

Comment: if you dont define an isolated scope, the directive will inherit from the controller by default. http://plnkr.co/edit/PVdzZEQFDkM0J3917HAS?p=preview

Comment: Won't solve OP issue of trying to log to console before `$http` completes. Will still be undefined when link initializes

Comment: i want to get CTH.length to custom pagination my list

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think the OP has shared enough information on his app architecture for us to know that for sure; but in my sample you are most likely correct.

Comment: @NitsanBaleli I can't believe I didn't know that.  Good catch!

Comment: @JeffryHouser , no it is a certainty since link will fire before `$scope.CTH` is defined in the `$http` callback

Comment: @charlietfl [Here is a sample architecture](http://plnkr.co/edit/UhqofYVCYCXdtWLcIRK3?p=preview) where the response from the $http call will be set before the link function:  . It uses two routes w/o custom controllers and the directive is in the second route.

Answer (score 0):

when the directive initializes, the scope.CTH is still not initialized since its initialization accurses inside an $http call.

one way to overcome this is to broadcast and event from the controller and catch it from inside the directive. see this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PVdzZEQFDkM0J3917HAS?p=preview) and angularjs scope's [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.test = "test";
    $scope.$broadcast('MyEvent')
  }, 500);
});


app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      scope.$on('MyEvent', function() {
        console.log(scope.test);
      })
    }
  }
})
```